# Authenticate user with User model, where I created user table in phpmyadmin and connected with django. Then migrated it to app

Tags: mysql, django

I'm new to Django. I try to make login user with authentication, but my model refers to table in PhpMyAdmin. I connected DB and made migration but when I try login it does not authenticate with my PhpMyAdmin table. I just want to know how to authenticate with the PhpMyAdmin user table and login into the website.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, phpmyadmin is just a tool to handle MySQL/Maria databases and is not the database itself. Can you add your settings.py so that we can check wether you connect to your mysql/Maria DB instance correctly?

Comment: Done.! Edited my post u can get my setting.py screenshot image. Thank u..

Comment: The settings seems to be fine. Is your mysql server running on 127.0.0.1? When you watch your database via pjpmyadmin, do you see any tables like django_sessions etc? Did you python manage.py migrate the models to your mysql database?

Comment: Yes it's. Now I want to login using the credentials of "snakeladder_user" table with authentication how can I do it. I attached the screenshot of migrated database in my post above. Pls help me out with this. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the user model with your own model which should be used for authentication.

Specify this in your settings.py like:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.SnakeladderUser'
```

This dotted pair describes the name of the Django app (which must be in your INSTALLED_APPS), and the name of the Django model that you wish to use as your user model.

Check out the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user